# python equivalent for const methods with type hints

Tags: python, constants, type-hinting, mypy

I'm trying to find the python equivalent of c++ `const` methods. That is,
methods that are **forbidden** to change *any* data member of their class.

```
from typing import Final

age: Final = 2
age += 3               # <----- warn about this -- works!

class Person:
    def __init__(self, age: int) -> None:
        self.age = age
    def happy_birthday(self: Final[Person]) -> None:
        self.age += 1  # <----- warn about this -- how?
```

I've never seen type hints used with `self` so it looks a bit weird (and doesn't work)

```
main.py:4: error: Cannot assign to final name "age"
main.py: note: In member "happy_birthday" of class "Person":
main.py:9: error: Final can be only used as an outermost qualifier in a variable annotation  [misc]
        def happy_birthday(self: Final[Person]) -> None:
                                 ^
```

Is there any *other* way to achieve this? Note that the attributes should still allow modification in other methods.

Comment: *"methods that are forbidden to change any data member of their class"* — I don't think there's any way to express that in Python. It's mostly a compiler optimisation thing in C. To not let your method modify any members, you'd simply not write any code in the method that modifies members. "We're all consenting adults here" is a core mantra of Python, if you don't want to do something, just don't do it.

Comment: The idea of const functions is not to allow them to modify the object on which they are called. There is no way to force a function not to change an object in Python, if the object isn't already immutable. Apart from that, type hints don't enforce anything to begin with, they just cause warnings in IDEs and compilers that support them.

Comment: @Grismar I feel like warning only is fine with OP, judging by the comment at self.age line.

Comment: @Grismar I'm looking for that warning. And also as a code-documenting plus: "Note fellow programmer, the method you are reading does *not* change the underlying object"

Comment: The only thing I can think of where a function would declare and simultaneously check anything about itself is a return type annotation. An appropriate type checker would warn when the function declared that it's going to return something but fails to do so. But that's somewhat incidentally, as return type annotations are largely for *callers* of the function. Besides that, *implementation is declaration*. Choose a good name to convey to other programmers that it's a non-mutating method.

Comment: Since there is no way to make Python guarantee it won't be changed anyway, just having the documentation state it seems just as safe. And I don't see what kind of warning you'd want a developer to see when using a method that wouldn't change an object? How would the compiler or editor infer that the caller *did* expect a change? Perhaps you can provide an example of the type of warning you'd expect under the hypothetical that you did have this kind of type hint?

Comment: @Grismar *If* this were possible, the type checker would report error on modifications *inside* the method. It's very similar to what ``Final`` already does indeed – I've expanded the [code on the mypy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=1ac1ff635bd3069e57f0b14f54c4cc2f) if you want to take a look.

Comment: While it is not easy to add type hints for this easily, you can still create a decorator that wraps `self` in a proxy object that disallows `setattr` and raises errors during runtime. Putting the decorator like this on top of a const method is also good for documentation.

Comment: It will not be simple. `const` has be used as an optimization helper since early 70's C language, and is deeply buried into the compiler. Not only changing an attribute of `self` should raise a warning but also calling a non const method from a const one. That means that the annotation should be on the method itself. The current static analysis toolf only care for variable types, and `Final` only declares the variable to have a special *const sub-type*. Handling const methods would certainly be an interesting addition, but hardly reachable in the current version of the language.

Answer (score 3):

If it doesn't have to be a type-hint solution, then you can do what PIG208 suggested in the comments. i.e. you can create a decorator that overwrites the `__setattr__` method to throw an exception when modifying any attributes inside the method.

This is also suitable to attach on a per-method basis:

```
def const_method(func):
    def wrapper(instance):
        class unsettable_class(instance.__class__):
            def __init__(self):
                super().__setattr__("__dict__", instance.__dict__)

            def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
                if hasattr(self, attr):
                    raise AttributeError(f"Trying to set value: {value} on the read-only attribute: {instance.__class__.__name__}.{attr}")
                super().__setattr__(attr, value)

        return func(unsettable_class())
    return wrapper
```

You can then use it the same as any other decorator:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, age: int) -> None:
        self.age = age

    @const_method
    def happy_birthday(self: "Person") -> None:
        self.age += 1 # throws an error since we are using the custom decorator

    def rebirth(self: "Person") -> None:
        self.age = 0 # will not throw an error since there is no decorator
```

Unfortunately, the downside is that this method won't give you syntax highlighting in your IDE like type hinting will though.

UPDATE: You can get autocompletion to work in a way that the code is still mypy-correct. Using `from __future__ import annotations` and dropping the `"` ("Person" -> Person) does the trick.

Comment: What a fantastic idea for a decorator. Making an object immutable in python is not an easy task, so I would combine this with gelidum-freeze https://github.com/diegojromerolopez/gelidum  I wonder if you one can find a trick around the limitations that this imposes on autocompletion because that really is unfortunate

Comment: Autocompletion works when using future-annotations and mypy is happy, see my edit.

Comment: While I favor creating a decorator for what the OP is asking for, creating a custom class in a decorator for all ordinary method call is too expensive (classes are kept forever and not garbage collected, so that would create a memory leak). 
An approach that would create  one custom `__setattr__` in the class where it decorates a method, though a bit lengthy in code to be done correctly, would be perfect, though!

Comment: @julaine do you have any unanswered question with your specific imutability needs? If not, would care asking? Just point me there, and I will be happy to answer.

Comment: @jsbueno No, I don't. But I have tinkered with trying to make objects immutable (including collection-like objects with methods like `__setitem__` and objects referencing non-trivial objects and numpy-arrays which are mutated in native code) and I found this is not something you can sketch up quickly in an SO-answer. You can only write an imperfect but helpful library, and I found gelidum-freeze to be that library so I wanted to post it here. The library also adresses @jsbueno's concerns about memory as it does not create new classes on usage.

Answer (score -1):

**There is no such thing.**

In C++, `const` is there for historical and compiler optimization reasons that are not relevant in Python. This notion does not seem to fit well in Python's object-oriented programming model, in which methods and data structures form cohesive units: the object.

Comment: thanks, but note that I *do* want some *other* methods to be able to change `age`. So I can't make it immutable.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I removed the second part altogether. I think I do understand the requirements but there are design issues in the example that make me doubt. If OP's question is specifically about python syntax, the answer is simply "you can't". But... if the question is interpreted as "How do I enforce rules inside an object?" I feel it requires a better, real example of what is OP trying to accomplish here, because the answer is more in the lines of "You don't, but there is a better, OOP way".

Comment: @kkm-stillwaryofSEpromises I never implied C++ is not OO. The 'notion' in the second sentence refers to OP's wish. What can you add or change to improve this post?